# Is it possible to limit the file size of an XML in MSXML with VB6?

Tags: xml, vb6, msxml, msxml6, msxml4

I there a possibility to limit the size of an XML upon creation in Vb6 using MSXML?

For example I have to create a like 2GB XML file, but instead I want it to be split in 4 files of 500MB or 2 files of 1GB.

Please let me know the right direction to take in solving this.

Thanks.

Comment: In a 32-bit program you are probably going to run out of memory fairly early to hold a bloated DOM for this much data anyway.  If you seriously want to create XML documents on such an unwieldy scale skip the DOM and use SAX or ad hoc logic.

Answer (score 0):

This code uses MSXML SAX to write huge amounts of XML, broken into smaller files by testing the size of the output as it goes.

It requires an IStream as `MXXMLWriter.output` and we don't have such an object opened directly on disk in VB6, so a reference to the "olelib" type library is used here.  You can get this at:

[Namespace Edanmo Visual Basic 6 OLELIB.TLB - OLE interfaces & functions v1.7](http://www.mvps.org/emorcillo/en/code/vb6/index.shtml)

This is a widely-used type library for such things.  The version at that link is actually 1.81 currently.

The code has a loop that writes out simple dummy XML, iterating from 1 to `NUM_DETAIL_ELEMS` as it goes.  A new output stream is opened on a new file every `FILE_LIMIT_BYTES` of output.  To check this, each `CHECK_LIMIT_INTERVAL` iteration the `MXXMLWriter` is flushed to the stream and the stream's size in bytes is checked.

Pretty basic really.

```
Option Explicit
'
'Simple demonstration of using MSXML SAX to create an XML document.
'
'Requires a reference to:
'
'   Edanmo's OLE interfaces and functions v 1.81 or similar.
'

Private Stream As olelib.IStream

Private Sub StreamOpen(ByVal FileName As String)
    Set Stream = _
        olelib.SHCreateStreamOnFile(FileName, _
                                    STGM_CREATE _
                                 Or STGM_WRITE _
                                 Or STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE)
End Sub

Private Sub StreamClose()
    Set Stream = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function StreamLength() As Long
    Dim STATSTG As olelib.STATSTG

    Stream.Stat STATSTG, STATFLAG_NONAME
    'Convert pseudo-Currency ULARGE_INTEGER to Long:
    StreamLength = STATSTG.cbSize * 10000@
End Function

Private Function StreamIsOpen() As Boolean
    StreamIsOpen = Not Stream Is Nothing
End Function

Private Sub cmdCreate_Click()
    Const CHECK_LIMIT_INTERVAL As Long = 100
    Const FILE_LIMIT_BYTES As Long = 1000000
    Const NUM_DETAIL_ELEMS As Long = 100000
    Dim Attributes As SAXAttributes
    Dim Writer As MSXML2.MXXMLWriter
    Dim Handler As MSXML2.IVBSAXContentHandler
    Dim I As Long
    Dim FileNum As Long

    Set Attributes = New MSXML2.SAXAttributes
    Set Writer = New MSXML2.MXXMLWriter
    Set Handler = Writer
    With Writer
        .omitXMLDeclaration = False
        .standalone = True
        .disableOutputEscaping = False
        .indent = False 'True = use vbNewLine and vbTab,
                        'False = no indenting.
'        .encoding = "ascii"
'        .encoding = "windows-1252"
        .encoding = "utf-8"
'        .encoding = "unicode"
        .byteOrderMark = True 'Has no effect for 8-bit encodings.
    End With
    For I = 1 To NUM_DETAIL_ELEMS
        If Not StreamIsOpen() Then
            FileNum = FileNum + 1
            StreamOpen "doc" & Format$(FileNum, "00") & ".xml"
            Writer.output = Stream
            With Handler
                .startDocument
                .startElement "", "", "document", Attributes
            End With
        End If
        With Handler
            If Not Writer.indent Then
                'Use custom whitespace:
                .ignorableWhitespace vbLf & Space$(4)
            End If
            With Attributes
                .addAttribute "", "", "a", "", Hex$(Int(Rnd() * &H7FFFFFFF))
                .addAttribute "", "", "b", "", Hex$(Int(Rnd() * &H7FFFFFFF))
                .addAttribute "", "", "c", "", Hex$(Int(Rnd() * &H7FFFFFFF))
            End With
            .startElement "", "", "detail", Attributes
            Attributes.Clear
            .characters ChrW$(&HD8&) _
                      & Format$(DateAdd("n", _
                                        Int(Rnd() * 10000000) - 5000000, _
                                        Now()), _
                                "dddddd ttttt")
            .endElement "", "", "detail"
        End With
        If I Mod CHECK_LIMIT_INTERVAL = 0 Then
            Writer.flush
            If StreamLength() >= FILE_LIMIT_BYTES Then GoSub CloseDocument
        End If
    Next
    If StreamIsOpen() Then GoSub CloseDocument
    lblStatus.Caption = "Done!"
    Exit Sub

CloseDocument:
    With Handler
        If Not Writer.indent Then
            .ignorableWhitespace vbLf
        End If
        .endElement "", "", "document"
        .endDocument
    End With
    StreamClose
    Return
End Sub
```